# Populate vectors using for loop

Tags: matlab, vector, for-loop

I have a solution to creating a vector for just one element of a matrix:

```
[dx,dy] = gradient(Im);
orient11 = [(-dx(1,1)) (dy(1,1)) 0];
```

where

```
size(orient11) =

0 0 0
```

ie for the first element of orient, namely orient11, is a vector. How do I do this for all the other elements, so I have orient12, orient13....orientnn. I know I need a for loop, however what object do I store the vectors into from the for loop? I have discovered I can't create a matrix of vectors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I have discovered I can't create a matrix of vectors': why not?

Comment: You are almost certainly not going about this the right way. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: instead of creating N variables that are vectors of length 3, why not create a Nx3 matrix?

Comment: I have an image, and I have the image gradients dx and dy of the image. these are scalar values for the gradient at each pixel of the image. I also want the gradient vectors. so for each pixel i have pix1 = [-dx(1,1) dy(1,1) 0]. where I append the z dimension. so in essence I want an object that stores nxn vectors of length 3.

pix12 = [-dx(1,2) dy(1,2) 0] 
pix2020 = [-dx(20,20) dy(20,20) 0]

and so on...

Comment: How would `orient12` be defined? Like so: `[(-dx(1, 2)) (dy(1, 2)) 0];`?

Comment: Eitan ^^ that's right. How do I implement a for loop to do this for every element for me up to orientnn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* try building an *N*-by-*N*-by-3 matrix, but it won't be so convenient to manipulate. This is because extracting a vector from this matrix would yield a 1-by-1-by-3 vector, which you would need to reshape. Definitely not fun.

Instead, I suggest that you build an *N*-by-*N* [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-117.html) of 1-by-3 vectors, like so:

```
[dx, dy] = gradient(Im);
vec = @(i)[-dx(i), dy(i), 0];
orient = arrayfun(vec, reshape(1:numel(dx), size(dx)), 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

To access a vector, use the curly braces. For example, the vector at the (1, 2) position would be:

```
orient12 = orient{1, 2};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi EitenT - this looks great. I'll have a play around with this, but this has essentially answered my intial question.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = -2:0.2:2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(v);
z = x .* exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);
[px,py] = gradient(z,.2,.2);

orient11 = [(-px(1,1)) (py(1,1)) 0]; % based off of your concatination there.
size(orient11)
```

I then get:

```
ans =

     1     3
```

If you're looking to just grab the first column of data from the gradients you have and want to just stack zeros with them, you can do this:

```
orient11 = [(-px(:,1)) (py(:,1)) zeros(size(px,1),1)];
```

Instead of a `for` loop.

Update:

```
Orient = zeros(size(px,1),3,size(px,2));
for n = 1:size(px,1)
    Orient(:,:,n) = [(-px(:,n)) (py(:,n)) zeros(size(px,1),1)];
end
```

The layout of `Orient` is now your -px, py, 0 in layers.  Each layer represents the column from the initial data.  So if you wanted to get access to row 4 column 14, you would call `Orient(4,:,14)`.

Hope that makes sense and helps!

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for your answer. Just out of interest if I replaced (:,1) with (:,:), would that then give me the vectors for each element in every column, not just the first. ie will this give me a vector field? of nxn element, with each element a vector of size [1 3]? Because that is what I am after.

Comment: @brucezepplin no that unfortunately won't work.  That would simply give you all the -px terms, then py terms then a bunch of 0 at the end.  The only way to quickly address that, off the top of my head, is a for loop using this same idea.  I'll see if I can't rattle something of in a few min.  I'll update my post with it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. .I'm seeing the logic to this. I now have my image split up into columns. and each columns contains all the element vectors for that column. Is there any way I can reshape Orient so that Orient holds all of the columns as per the image dimensions? I'd rather that the vectors were not split into their respective columns, but store all the vectors into one object.  I'll check the cat function in the mean time and hopefully i'll figure it out!